# Change language for ADODB.Recordset or ADODB.Connection

Tags: vba, excel

When I retrieve data with a recordset from a connection I cannot control Date Language. This is how I retrieve Data:

```
Set rsData = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rsData = conODBC.Execute(sql)
```

The SQL statement has the below line:

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DB_MONTH), 'MM'),'MON')||DB_YEAR AS DATE_STR
```

it converts DB_MONTH and DB_YEAR to something like DEC16 and works perfectly fine with SQL Developer.

However if it comes as Recordset Field with VBA the Date is converted to German (I'm working with a German Excel) and I receive DEZ16.

This becomes a problem when I unload the Data into the sheet and continue to work with it since I have no control of how my data string comes back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set your data language to desired value before you run your query. Should be something like this:

```
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.CommandText = "ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'AMERICAN';"
cmd.Execute
```

Comment: This solved the problem. I didn't use the Command object but executed conODBC.Execute ("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'AMERICAN'") and closed the connection afterwards. After open the settings were as set.